# Usage of は and が in 文明が進むと、社会は複雑さを増す

Tags: particle-は, particle-が, は-and-が

> 文明が進むと、社会は複雑さを増す。

In this sentence,

1 - What are the reasons for using が and は particles in their respective places?

2 - Could we replace any of these two particles with the other one? If yes, how would that change the meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What are the reasons for using が and は particles in their respective places?

文明が進むと is a [subordinate clause](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subordinate_clause.htm) (the と-clause) of this sentence. Since 文明 is not the topic of the whole sentence but the subject of a subordinate clause, が imust be used as a simple subject marker. On the other hand, 社会は複雑さを増す is the main clause of this sentence. Since 社会 is the topic of this whole sentence, は has to be used.

The rule of thumb is that you cannot usually use は in subordinate clauses, which includes relative clauses, when-clauses, if-clauses, and so on. (As an exception, a contrastive-wa may appear in subordinate clauses.)

> 2 - Could we replace any of these two particles with the other one?

No, you can't (unless an explicit contrastive meaning is clearly intended).